# how to use full-text-search in SQLite database in UWP

Tags: full-text-search, win-universal-app, entity-framework-core

I have a `UWP` project that used `SQLite` with `EF7`, I want to know if I can use `FTS` ( full-text-search ) in it or not? any example?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>EF7</strike> EF Core uses [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.data.sqlite) under the hood for SQLite. The version of SQLite 3 that this package loads on UWP supports FTS.

*General note: the following is true of all platforms, not just UWP.*

EF Core (as of RC2), by default, creates regular tables, but you can manually make it use FTS.

If you want to use FTS, you will need to modify migrations and queries.

1. Migrations/table creation

The migrations will create regular tables by default. To use FTS, you need to make FTS tables instead. You can to this by writing migrations manually

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE enrondata1 USING fts3(content TEXT);") // FTS table
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE TABLE enrondata2(content TEXT);"); // ordinary table
```

If you are not using migrations, you will need to still provide this SQL explicitly. Instead of using `context.Database.EnsureCreate()`, call `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql)` to create tables.

2. Query

By default, EF Core will use "LIKE" when it constructs queries. To leverage FTS, you need to use "MATCH" instead.

```
 context.EnronData2.FromSql(@"SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata1 WHERE content MATCH 'linux';"); // uses FTS search
 context.EnronData1.Where(e => e.Content.Contains("linux")); // uses regular, slow search
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1 for more info

Comment: sorry about delay, because I was on vacation, and My database is dynamic, I mean data in it will sometimes change, do u have any example that I can download it or see it?

Comment: @Maryam i don't know whether i am too late to the party, but are there any obvious problems that would occur with mundane UPDATE statements in fts tables? EF Core's JOIN, INSERT and SELECT wrappers work fine with fts5.